# How to add new line in a JLabel with variables

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I understand you can make a new line using `<html> <br> </html>` but when I add a variable (is a string type) to the text of a label this command doesn't work any more.

`label.setText("blahblahblah" + variable + "<html><br>blahblahblah</html>");`

I need it to output:

blahblahblah
blahblahblah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have the `<html>` tag as the first thing in your String:

```
label.setText("<html>blahblahblah" + variable + "<br>blahblahblah</html>");
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
label.setText("<html>blahblahblah" + variable + "<br>blahblahblah</html>");
```